# Haskell in SPOJ: "Wrong answer" in problem, but correct in my computer

Tags: perl, haskell

Today, I submitted solutions on [SPOJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPOJ) to [the COINS problem](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/COINS/). I got the Fortran and the Perl solutions accepted, but I got "Wrong answer" in the Haskell solution. I thought that perhaps my code was faulty at some point, but the results for 200K numbers (100K in the upper limit and 100K in the lower one) are exactly as per the Perl solution as can be seen below:

```
angelv@vaso:~/Dropbox/ProgrammingGym/SPOJ$ seq 1000000000 -1 999900001 > p346.in
angelv@vaso:~/Dropbox/ProgrammingGym/SPOJ$ seq 0 100000 >> p346.in
angelv@vaso:~/Dropbox/ProgrammingGym/SPOJ$
angelv@vaso:~/Dropbox/ProgrammingGym/SPOJ$ ./p346.pl < p346.in > p346.po
angelv@vaso:~/Dropbox/ProgrammingGym/SPOJ$ ghc --make -o p346.exe p346.hs
angelv@vaso:~/Dropbox/ProgrammingGym/SPOJ$ ./p346.exe < p346.in > p346.ho
angelv@vaso:~/Dropbox/ProgrammingGym/SPOJ$
angelv@vaso:~/Dropbox/ProgrammingGym/SPOJ$
angelv@vaso:~/Dropbox/ProgrammingGym/SPOJ$ diff p346.ho p346.po
angelv@vaso:~/Dropbox/ProgrammingGym/SPOJ$
angelv@vaso:~/Dropbox/ProgrammingGym/SPOJ$ head -n 5 p346.ho
4243218150
4243218150
4243218150
4243218150
4243218150
angelv@vaso:~/Dropbox/ProgrammingGym/SPOJ$
```

Is there any way to find what could be going on (perhaps the last few lines of the generated output?).

Comment: 1) Your Perl solution could be wrong (even if it passed 10 random tests and has been accepted). 2) You may have made a stupid mistake like submitting the wrong file or printing an extra newline, or not printing it. If you'd like to discuss your solution, please post both Perl and Haskell versions, otherwise there is not much to say.

Comment: It is a bit frustrating that one cannot see even part of the output to figure out what is going on. I'm pretty sure that the files I submitted are exactly the ones that produce in my computer exactly the same output for 200K test cases. Do you know for sure that the test cases provided by SPOJ are selected randomly? That could make a difference perhaps...

Comment: No, I've never heard of SPOJ, but given their problem description one cannot assume that the input is always the same. This is only one of the many possible explanations why your Perl code was accepted, and the Haskell code was not. Without your code we cannot tell you what's wrong with it. If you ask about how to debug Haskell code, this can help: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Debugging

Comment: I tried to write a solution to that problem and it was not accepted neither. It gives correct results on known inputs (2,12,1e9). Just in case you are interested, http://hpaste.org/fastcgi/hpaste.fcgi/view?id=28403#a28403

Comment: SPOJ uses the same inputs each time, not random inputs. Most often (almost always) the problem is that your program has a bug that is not caught by the simple test cases (small or large) you tried it on, but is caught by the special inputs they've designed especially to catch the kind of bug you made. Just keep trying. Coincidentally, I have an accepted solution to that problem... my wrong solution got fixed after taking care of integer overflow (in C), but your bug could be something else. Unless you post your solution(s), there's nothing more that can be said.

Comment: In case it helps, here there are links to both solutions. In Perl (http://pastebin.com/att7L9nb) and in Haskell (http://pastebin.com/AL2eRq6D). If anyone can shed some light on why the Haskell solution is not accepted, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, there isn't any way to look for the output in SPOJ. But I think that you can generate errors so the SPOJ compiler says "Hey, you have this runtime error!", but it would be induced by you, so, you can see where is it failing. (I haven't tested it, but.. if you return a non-zero value (if it is possible in Haskell) won't SPOJ tell you that ending number?)

I can't see your Haskell code, and I assume you have done other problems in Haskell already, so, you have take care of those little errors like "leaving a blank linke at the end" or re-reading the last line of input.

Sorry for my bad English, and sorry if my answer isn't what you've expected (The quest. I don't use SPOJ frecuently, and maybe there is another way, but the only one that comes to my mind is "If you want to debug it, throw errors and differentiate them".)

I don't know if this should be an answer or should be commented on the first post, but I can't add a comment there, I think it's because I'm new here.

Edit: I've asked in Haskell IRC channel, and a very gentle user told me about "System.Exit".
Take a look, I hope it helps you:
http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/System-Exit.html

Maybe there's another way to "debug" your program from SPOJ, but I don't know how. Have you tried commenting on the problem, or asking in the forum? You can also post your Haskell code in Haskell's IRC and ask if someone can take a look at it.